# Как на nginx настроить 301 редирект c www? (ругается на незащищенное соединение)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx, ssl, редирект

Есть необходимость на `nginx` настроить 301 редирект c **www**

По рекомендациям это должно быть примерно так:

```
server {
    server_name www.devisers.in;
    return 301 $scheme://devisers.in$request_uri;
}
```

Но, у меня server_name задан переменной (локальный и реальный хост отличаются)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ${VIRTUAL_HOST};
}
```

Как в таком случае прописать правило c **www** ?

**UDP**
Прописал отдельной записью

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  www.${VIRTUAL_HOST};
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Но, при переходе по www браузеры ругаются на

> Соединение не установлено: Вероятная угроза безопасности

(На сайте установлен ssl сетификат)

**UDP**
вот в таком виде

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  www.${VIRTUAL_HOST};
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name$request_uri;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    # ssl
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/${CERT_NAME}/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/${CERT_NAME}/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-...;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
}
```

получаю ошибку

> 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.17.6

Comment: подставьте вместо `devisers.in` вашу переменную `${VIRTUAL_HOST}`. в обоих местах.

Comment: @ aleksandr barakin если просто подставить вместо исходного,
`server_name www.${VIRTUAL_HOST};
    return 301 $scheme://${VIRTUAL_HOST}$request_uri;`
 то получаю ошибку загрузки

Comment: добавьте listen 443 ssl; и сертификаты для www.${VIRTUAL_HOST}

Comment: @eri добавить отдельной записью `server {
    listen 443 ssl http2; # ssl
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/${CERT_NAME}/fullchain.pem; .... }` или заменить `listen 80` на `listen 443` ?

Comment: если делаю замену 80 порта на то, что описал, то получаю ошибку 502

Comment: Не отдельно, не заменить, просто добавь в этот же хост

Comment: @eri обновил в условии как прописываю и что получаю

Comment: @eri нет больше никаких идей?

Comment: @Вася надопробовать